# Howto rotate image using jquery rotate plugin?

Tags: jquery, image, rotation, jquery-rotate

How do you rotate an image using [jQuery-rotate](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/) plugin?

I have tried the following and it doesn't seem to work:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>View Photo</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.rotate.1-1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var angle = 0;
setInterval ( function (e) {
    rotate();
}, 100 );
function rotate() {
    angle = angle + 1;
    $('#pic').rotate(angle);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img border="0" src="player.gif" name="pic" id="pic">
</body>
</html>
```

Other methods that are supported by most browsers are wanted too, thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You've got a 404 on jQuery and the jQuery plugin. Because of that, your page is throwing a JavaScript error, that $ is not defined.

You need to learn basic JavaScript debugging techniques. A quick search found this article that looks like a good place for you to start:

- [JavaScript Debugging Techniques with Firebug](http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/javascript/javascript-debugging-techniques-with-firebug-8-04-20/page1.html)

Answer (score 7):

Your logic for rotating the image is right. It will work if executed when the document is ready.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var angle = 1;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            $("#pic").rotate(angle);
            /* angle += 1; Increases the rotating speed */
        }, 100);
    });
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: To elaborate on jvan's response: The reason to put it into document.ready is because the webpage DOM isn't ready yet to be modified (or 'looked at' by your javascript). More information on the ready event is here: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$(document).ready()

Comment: n.b. I'm just being pedantic, but I noticed Tom's not using the XHMTL doctype, the //<![CDATA[ is only needed if your using XHTML. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag

Answer (score 3):

Once you fix your jquery include issues, you can fix your script. Your syntax is wrong: Here is the fix:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var angle = 1;

    $(document).ready(function(angle) {
        setInterval(function(angle) {
                $("#pic").rotate(angle);
                /* angle += 1; Increases the rotating speed */
        }, 100);
    });
//]]>
</script>
```