# How to CONSTANTLY rotate an object with jquery?

Tags: jquery, image, web, css, rotation

OKAY! Here's the situation. I've got a jQuery plugin that's animating a background-image in my header to constantly scroll left-to-right. I have a .png of a wheel sitting on this header. I need to have the wheel constantly spinning with the moving background.

CSS3- Yes I could use CSS3, but then some poor soul using Internet Explorer would see a stationary wheel on a moving background which would be weird.

jQuery Plugins- This is what I'd LIKE to use, but I have yet to find one that will constantly rotate the image. Most only rotate by a certain angle when you activate it.

If anybody has any thoughts, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Maybe show some code and/or image examples. If compatibility is important, have you considered using an animated GIF?

Comment: Have you thought of using an animated GIF for the wheel?

Comment: I'm speculating that the rotation of the wheel should sorta match the movement of the road, and thusly it would be nice to have some JavaScript variables to work with that would allow these to sync up. Is that a fair guess, @KThornbloom?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try this:

http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples

```
    var rotation = function (){
   $("#img").rotate({
      angle:0, 
      animateTo:360, 
      callback: rotation,
      easing: function (x,t,b,c,d){        // t: current time, b: begInnIng value, c: change In value, d: duration
          return c*(t/d)+b;
      }
   });
}
rotation();
```

Comment: how would I stop the rotation?

Comment: The link no longer works - is there another repository for this library?

Answer (score 6):

Check out my post:

- [Rotate and Fly off elements with jQuery and CSS3](http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2010/12/27/rotate-and-fly-off-elements-with-jquery-and-css3/)
- [See the DEMO](http://sarfraznawaz2005.kodingen.com/demos/jquery/jquery_rotating_elements/rotate.html)

[image]

Comment: Ooh, fancy! Nice and smooth, too.

Answer (score 4):

It's not jQuery as such, but if you want to do something constantly in JavaScript, use `setInterval()`, like so:

```
setInterval("alert('Rotate!');", 100);
```

But replace the alert with your rotation code, and the interval is in milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like that's the key, and Sarfraz down there has examples for me to look at with that code.

Comment: True that. For what it's worth, his code contains `setInterval()`. And it's way nifty.

Comment: Hmm, I'm still a little confused. Sarfraz's method only works once you click on it, and only rotates once although the title of the blog says "continuous rotation". Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: It is the conditional that is in Sarfraz' code, if (counter != -360) {...}. Once that is no longer true, it stops a-rotatin'. Just for completeness, I might add an else statement to clearInterval() at that point.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want [this answer to a related question about rotating images with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365820/howto-rotate-image-using-jquery-rotate-plugin/1710976#1710976)...

But it's purely a rotating wheel, then a two or three frame animated gif will probably be easier, faster, and less CPU-intensive...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The reason I didn't go for an animated gif is because I wanted the animation to be nice and smooth, and also to be able to easily control the speed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery plugin for rotating image like 3d object:

[pic360 plugin](http://plugins2.jquery.it/plugin-tags/pic360)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a plugin for this, which works with internet explorer 7 and 8 as well!
Here you go: http://wp-dreams.com/jquery-element-rotation-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

@dietbacon asked how to stop a rotation. Since I cannot yet comment, I will answer here.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40435019/2420998) answer, I wrote a function that does an infinite rotation in a given element and that can be cancelled.