# jQuery Animate transform infinite

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to set infinite rotating but it doesn't work.

```
function AnimateRotate(angle) {
    var $elem = $('.icon-repeat');

    $({deg: 0}).animate({deg: angle}, {
        duration: 5000,
        step: function(now) {
            $elem.css({
                transform: 'rotate(' + now + 'deg) infinite'
            });
        }
    });
}
```

That is my code, and this line **transform: 'rotate(' + now + 'deg) infinite'** ..
if I remove **infinite**  it works for one rotate, but I need to rotate infinite..
I have to write it in JS, I think...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Infinite rotation animation using CSS and Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019159/infinite-rotation-animation-using-css-and-javascript)

Comment: no, not the same problem

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/13h55t8x/

Comment: I need to rotate infinite...

Comment: rotate forever, dont stop

Comment: with specified angle? how should it works?

Comment: And I need to do that in js function

Comment: It works from 0 to 360.. and that rotates one time, but i need to rotate infinite times

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sUHKh/159/  to rotate like that but with code in JS

Answer (score 3):

Try this, You should set the "repeat" value. AnimateRotate(degree, repeatcount).

In your case set the repeatcount as "***infinite***".

```
function AnimateRotate(angle,repeat) {
    var duration= 1000;
    setTimeout(function() {
        if(repeat && repeat == "infinite") {
            AnimateRotate(angle,repeat);
        } else if ( repeat && repeat > 1) {
            AnimateRotate(angle, repeat-1);
        }
    },duration)    
    var $elem = $('.icon-repeat');

    $({deg: 0}).animate({deg: angle}, {
        duration: duration,
        step: function(now) {
            $elem.css({
                'transform': 'rotate('+ now +'deg)'
            });
        }
    });
}
AnimateRotate(45,"infinite");
```

[Here the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nandhakumarsri9/cg3uftza/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Here goes another answer, one that uses the `complete` callback of the `animate()` function instead of `setInterval()`, and that can be canceled:

```js
function rotateForEver($elem, rotator) {
    if (rotator === void(0)) {
        rotator = $({deg: 0});
    } else {
        rotator.get(0).deg = 0;
    }

    return rotator.animate(
        {deg: 360},
        {
            duration: 5000,
            easing: 'linear',
            step: function(now){
                $elem.css({transform: 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)'});
            },
            complete: function(){
                rotateForEver($elem, rotator);
            },
        }
    );
}
```

You would then use it like this:

```js
$(function() {
    var $rotator = rotateForEver($('.icon-repeat'));
    $('#some-button-to-cancel').click(function() {
        $rotator.stop();
    });
});
```

Comment: This solution is great because you can update the element while rotating without affecting the animation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it with `setInterval()`:

```
function AnimateRotate(angle) {
    var $elem = $('.icon-repeat');
    setInterval(function(){
       $({deg: 0}).animate({deg: angle}, {
          duration: 5000,
          step: function(now) {
            $elem.css({
                transform: 'rotate(' + now + 'deg) infinite'
            });
          }
       });
    }
}
```

and call it like:

```
AnimateRotate(360);
```

#### [Updated demo as suggested by *`bemol`*.](http://jsfiddle.net/13h55t8x/2/)

Comment: my code is good... i dont need setinterval... only INFINITE is not good... doesnt rotate when I add it

Comment: this code will work if you remove `infinite` (this one is for `animation` not for transform) and add set interval to `5000` (same as duration)

Comment: I know that that code works if remove infinite, but I need to do that idea... idea is to rotate infinite

Comment: thats why `setInterval` is here