# Ignoring attempts to close x with y

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

Ruby on Rails sometimes gives you annoying "Ignoring attempts to close x with y" [warnings arising from assert_select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671221/rails-assert-selects-annoying-warnings). Often these warnings are the result of invalid HTML, but sometimes they appear even if the HTML is valid. The error in my case looks like this while running `ruby test/functional/my_controller_test.rb` :

```
..ignoring attempt to close div with h2
  opened at byte 8551, line 207
  closed at byte 9554, line 243
  attributes at open: {"class"=>"my_css_class", "id"=>"object_1"}
  text around open: "  \r\n  \r\n  \r\n  \r\n\r\n  <div class=\"my_css_class"
  text around close: "</a>\r\n      </h2>\r\n\r\n      <span"
```

But there is no attempt to close a div with a h2 tag. I tried a HTML validator, but without success. [The -W0 parameter mentioned by Giles seems to help](http://gilesbowkett.blogspot.de/2009/10/ignoring-attempt-to-close-foo-with-bar.html) - `ruby -W0 test/functional/my_controller_test.rb` gives no longer a warning, but this does not work for `rake test:whatever`. What does -W0 do, and how can you avoid using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various [command line options for Ruby unit tests](http://scottpatten.ca/2007/10/ruby-unit-test-command-line-options.html). -W does not belong to them, it is a command line option for pure Ruby. As `ruby --help` says, the ruby `-W[level]` command line option sets the warning level for Ruby; 0=silence, 1=medium, 2=verbose (default). `ruby -W0` sets the warning level to silence.

```
$ ruby --help
  [...]
  -w              turn warnings on for your script
  -W[level]       set warning level; 0=silence, 1=medium, 2=verbose (default)
```

The -W flag also activates the "verbose" mode of Ruby. Mislav has a good explanation of [the verbose mode](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2011/06/ruby-verbose-mode/). From within Ruby code, verbosity can be set and tested with the value of the $VERBOSE global variable, which can have 3 states: nil ("0"), false ("1"), and true ("2"). So you can suppress warning for your Test::Unit test by setting

```
$VERBOSE = nil
```

in your `test_helper.rb`. For running RSpecs test you can [suppress ruby warning similarly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591509/suppress-ruby-warnings-when-running-specs).

Answer (score 3):

In test helper:

```
class ActionController::TestCase  
  include Devise::TestHelpers
  Paperclip.options[:log] = false
  Mocha::Deprecation.mode = :disabled

  #
  # kill verbsity
  #
  verbosity = $-v
  $-v = nil

end
```