# ignoring attempt to close li with a

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, html

I am a bit confused as to why this line `<li><a href= /login class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" ></a></li>` is throwing the warning line `ignoring attempt to close li with a` when i run my test. I have read multiple questions similar to this  such as [Ignoring attempts to close x with y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366502/ignoring-attempts-to-close-x-with-y) but as far as i understand that line of html code is valid. If i replace it with `<li><%= link_to login_path, login_path %><li>` , i don't understand how to treat and  remove this warning. I also dont want to silence the warnings that rails test throw off because of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it supposed to be `<li><a href="/login" class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" ></a></li>`. You forgot to give `""` to your `href`.

Comment: Thanks @Johan Pranata, the `" "` made the difference.