# How can I get the index of an ancestor within another ancestor?

Tags: jquery, list

I've got a list that's got a `mouseover` event bound:

```
myObject = function()
{

    this.listTemplate = $("<ul></ul>")
        .mouseover(function(event) {
          //Do mouse over stuff
        })
        .click(function(event) {
          //Do click stuff
        });

    //...more stuff
}
```

Later on in my code, I'm populating this list with items returned by an Ajax call, which all works swimmingly...

In the Ajax success method:

```
//...
$(items).each(function(item) {
    $("<li />").append("<a />").text(item.value)
   .appendTo(templateList);
});
//...
```

In my `mouseover` event, the `event.target` returns the anchor as expected, but I need the index of the `li` ancestor (within the `ul`) of the anchor I'm hovering over.

Given that the content of the `li` could be more complex than just the anchor, does jQuery provide a simple way of finding that out?

i.e. I'm hovering over some descendent of `li[0]` or `li[4]` etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/), like this:

```
.mouseover(function(e) {
  var i = $(e.target).closest('ul').children().index($(e.target).closest('li'));
})
```

From the docs:

> If `.index()` is called on a collection of elements and a DOM element or jQuery object is passed in, `.index()` returns an integer indicating the position of the passed element relative to the original collection.

This goes up to the `<ul>`, gets it's children (the `<li>` elements), and gets the index of the `<li>` containing the link in that collection.

---

Alternatively, instead of using `event.target` you can do it a bit more cleanly with [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), like this:

```
$("&lt;ul&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;").delegate('li', 'mouseover', function() {
  var index = $(this).index();
})
```

In this case, `this` refers to the `<li>` so the normal `.index()` call just gets it's index relative to it's siblings, if it's an option...it's a bit simpler route to take.

---

Last, kind of tangential to the question, you don't need to encode `<` and `>`, you can just have:

```
$("<li />").append("<a />").text(item.value)
```

If you're doing this for XHTML/validation purposes, [just wrap your script in `CDATA` to validate correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag).

Comment: I dunno why I thought I had to encode those... did you in the past?  Anyway, fixed now, thanks.

Comment: @BenAlabaster - It should...something else is as play if that's not working, possibly validate your page, see if something's not matching...this hasn't even been an issue that I can remember seeing :)

Comment: +1 Thanks, that was just the ticket.  That was the last thing preventing my object from working as I wanted it to ;)