# How to remove `//<![CDATA[` and end `//]]>`?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, cdata

How can I remove the `(//<![CDATA[ , //]]>`) blocks; tags inside a `script` element.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var l=new Array();
    ..........................
    ..........................
    //]]>
</script>
```

Looks like it can be done with `preg_replace()` but havent found a solution that works for me.

What regex would I use?

Comment: Just curious why you want to remove those two lines?

Comment: bomanden: @JonathanM is right, you may not need to remove these elements. See [When is a CDATA section necessary within a script tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag) and [Is CDATA really necessary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215261/is-cdata-really-necessary). Think it over.

Comment: Ok - Its just that the Javascript dont fire .. so the code is not executed .. It is when I use Alan's solution. 
But thanks on the info.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following regex will do it...

```
$removed = preg_replace('/^\s*\/\/<!\[CDATA\[([\s\S]*)\/\/\]\]>\s*\z/', 
                        '$1', 
                        $scriptText);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/4zOOYEEB).

Comment: Hi Alex .. 
No unfortunately not. Do know why - but got a Alans working.
Perhaps you can see the difference between the two solutions. 
Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 21):

You don't need regex for a static string.

Replace those parts of the texts with nothing:

```
$string = str_replace("//<![CDATA[","",$string);
$string = str_replace("//]]>","",$string);
```

Comment: What if it includes that text as part of the `script` body, perhaps as a string?

Comment: I like this solution far better than the Regex option, much cleaner to read.

Answer (score 6):

If you must...

```
$s = preg_replace('~//<!\[CDATA\[\s*|\s*//\]\]>~', '', $s);
```

This will remove the whole line containing each tag without messing up the indentation of the enclosed code.

Answer (score 3):

If `<![CDATA[` contains some html special character, e.g. `&`, `"`, `'`, `<`, `>` and you will work with the rest of the string as it is still XML, you should escape those chars.
Otherwise you will make your XML invalid.

```php
function removeCDataFromString(string $string)
{
    return preg_replace_callback(
        '~<!\[CDATA\[(.*)\]\]>~',
        function (array $matches) {
            return htmlspecialchars($matches[1], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE, 'UTF-8');
        },
        $string
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try,

```
$s=str_replace(array("//<![CDATA[","//]]>"),"",$s);
```

Answer (score 1):

use `str_replace()` instead of `preg_replace()` it's lot easier

```
$var = str_replace('<![CDATA[', '', $var);
$var = str_replace(']]','',$var);
echo $var;
```

Answer (score 0):

I use like this to remove `<![CDATA[]]` but on single line now work for me, dont know if for multiple line string.

```
preg_match_all('/CDATA\[(.*?)\]/', $your_string_before_this, $datas); 
$string_result_after_this = $datas[1][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$nodeText = '<![CDATA[some text]]>';
$text = removeCdataFormat($nodeText);    

public function removeCdataFormat($nodeText)
{
    $regex_replace = array('','');
    $regex_patterns = array(
        '/<!\[CDATA\[/',
        '/\]\]>/'
   );
   return trim(preg_replace($regex_patterns, $regex_replace, $nodeText));
}
```