# why does the w3 validator check within the <script> tag and raise errors?

Tags: html, validation

I am trying to validate my page using the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.veepiz.com/afroprofileview-viewprofile-33-radio_and_weasel.html&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.1) but it keeps looking within the script tag of the javascript and failing. any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It gets treated as PCDATA since it's XHTML ( XML ). Mark it as CDATA per [When is a CDATA section necessary within a script tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag) and you should be ok:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
...code...
//]]>
</script>
```

Alternatively you can stop attempting to use XHTML by using HTML 5, or throw the code in an external JS file if it's feasible.