# How to escape '$' and '#' in Facelets/EL?

Tags: escaping, facelets, el

I'm using Java Facelets and jQuery, however the expression

```
$('...')
```

in jQuery conflicts with EL expression, how do I escape the jQuery's one?

I'd like to escape a large chunk of Javascript, too.

**ANSWERED**

To convert the existing JSP to Facelets xhtml, it's convenient to just wrap the existing javascript by `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>`.  However, the output scripts for `<script>` are wrapped by `<!-- -->` comment, which conflicts with CDATA section:

```
<script><![CDATA[ scripts... ]]></script>

=> <script><!-- <![CDATA[ scripts... ]]> --></script>
```

To resolve this problem, you should also comment out the CDATA:

```
<script>/* <![CDATA[ */ scripts... /* ]]> */</script>

=> <script><!-- /* <![CDATA[ */ scripts... /* ]]> */--></script>
```

See also [When is a CDATA section necessary within a script tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag).

Comment: As per your update, the real problem comes clear: you're writing JS code raw in a XML file and the XML parser is falling over `$` which should be represented as `&amp;`. Apart from the ugly `CDATA` workaround, the best solution is to put JS code in its own `.js` file. After all, the question title and body does not describe the real problem and is therefore misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should normally not conflict. EL uses `${}` syntax. Anyway, you could either use [`jQuery()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) instead (the `$()` is just a shorthand) or simply put JS code in its own `.js` file.

Answer (score 11):

Should anyone need to, the [Expression Language Specification Version 2.2 Maintenance Release](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr245/index.html) describes how to escape EL expressions:

> To generate literal values that
>   include the character sequence `"${"`
>   or `"#{"`, the developer can choose to
>   use a composite expression as shown
>   here:
>
> ```
> ${'${'}exprA}
> #{'#{'}exprB}
> ```
>
> The resulting values would then be the
>   strings `${exprA}` and `#{exprB}`.
>
> Alternatively, the escape characters
>   `\$` and `\#` can be used to escape
>   what would otherwise be treated as an
>   eval-expression. Given the
>   literal-expressions:
>
> ```
> \${exprA}
> \#{exprB}
> ```