# Entry point for jquery document

Tags: jquery

In every JQuery tutorial the entry point is always like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   ...
});
```

But in [sdoc](https://github.com/voloko/sdoc) project it has different entry point as for my novice's view.
Here's the code snippet and [there](https://github.com/voloko/sdoc/blob/master/lib/sdoc/generator/template/direct/resources/panel/index.html) the full file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    //<![CDATA[
    function placeholder() {
        ...
    }
    $(function() {
       placeholder();
       ...
    })
    //]]>
</script>
```

The question: Is `$(function()..)` the entry point for jquery script? And if it does why it differ from traditional approach? Thanks

Comment: Yes, I believe that is just a shorthand for $(document).ready

Comment: what's that CDATA stuff there for?  If it's there to comment-out the script from browsers that don't understand it, that hasn't been necessary since Netscape 1.0

Comment: For my understanding it says to parser that data inside is only character data, not markup. And here's answer for your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the same. From the [jQuery documentation for .ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> All three of the following syntaxes
>   are equivalent:
>
> ```
> $(document).ready(handler)
> $().ready(handler) (this is not recommended)
> $(handler)
> ```

Comment: $(handler) is just an easy shortcut for running a script onDOMReady.

Answer (score 1):

`$(function() { ... })` is just short hand for `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`