# JQuery not working when I load the page

Tags: jquery, fadein

I am trying to fade in whatever shows up in (div id="content").

I have this to load JQuery to the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="rocoffee.js"></script>
```

And here is what is in rocoffee.js

```
$(function(){
$('#content').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

I have yet to see this event take place when I load my page.

Note: I do have a jquery.js file to use, but I tried to use the above based on answers I've read. Same outcome regardless.

Comment: Can we see the HTML too?  It'll help to give some more context to the situation.  Also, check the console to see if there are any errors which would prevent this from happening.

Comment: Do you have other libraries on your page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As no HTML code is availabe, i would assume that the `div` is initially visible, and therefore suggest that `fadeIn` does not make much sense.

Try setting the `div` `hidden`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to hide it first!

http://jsfiddle.net/wVTab/

```
$(function(){
    $('#content').hide();        
    $('#content').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Comment: Wow, that was obvious. I thought I had taken care of that in my css, I guess not. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#content').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

instead

Comment: compare with http://stackoverflow.com/a/5749828/1689451 -- the OPs syntax is ok.

Comment: that makes no difference - the 2 methods are equivalent http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: The `$(function(){ });` form is an alias to jQuery's DOMReady function.

Comment: Yeah, thanx ^^ As everyone else here stated, it was kinda obvious that a div should be `invidible` first for it to `fadeIn`