# xml "<" parsing error

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm trying to write some JavaScript code in a gxp file and I get a parsing exception at the "<" character in the "if" construct. Any ideas how to escape it?

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
 var current = 0;
 var values = [];

 function goNext() {
  if (current < values.length - 1) {
   current = current + 1;
   update();
  }
 }
</script>
```

*org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.*

Answer (score 2):

Put it in a `<![CDATA[ ...... ]]>` and then try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
..
..
your code
..
..
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Beat me to it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
if (values.length - 1 > current) { 

}
```

:)

Comment: if '<' is problematic then reverse the operands and use '>' :)

Answer (score 1):

`<` is an XML entity.

[Hide the Javascript code from XML](http://javascript.about.com/library/blxhtml.htm):

```
<script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
 var current = 0;
 var values = [];

 function goNext() {
  if (current < values.length - 1) {
   current = current + 1;
   update();
  }
 }
// ]]></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because your code is "not protected" by a  section.

you should try

```
<script type="text/JavaScript"><![CDATA[
var current = 0;
 var values = [];

 function goNext() {
  if (current < values.length - 1) {
   current = current + 1;
   update();
  }
 }
]]></script>
```

This way the "<" won't be treated as XML.