# Prevent lxml from touching data in <script> tags

Tags: python, html-parsing, lxml

I'm trying to write a python script that modifies the contents of <script> tag in files I'm parsing. I'm using lxml.html (as opposed to BeautifulSoup, etc.) for this due to its speed. The contents of script tag are surrounded in comment tags (<!-- and -->):

```
<script>
<!--
...
-->
</script>
```

The problem is when I try something like `scriptNode.text = '<!-- ...` lxml modifies the angle brackets to their html representations (& lt; and & gt;) when I write the html back to file. I tried escaping them in the string ('\< ...'), but that doesn't seem to help.

Looking at most modern websites, it looks like those comment tags are not needed. I can remove them, but many of the scripts also use some html within them and if those get modified to their HTML representation as well, that's a problem.

I'm surprised that lxml is modifying this data at all, last I heard HTML parsers are designed to avoid modifying/interpreting data within <script> tags.

Is there a setting/command I can use to prevent this from happening?

Thanks

Comment: You should not be putting a HTML comment inside of a script tag, that is likely the source of your problem.

Comment: @mikerobi: that's not the main problem, I also mentioned that this affects other variables in scripts, for example `var somearg = '<h3>test</h3>'` becomes `var somearg = '&lt;h3&gt;test&lt;/h3&gt;'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put them in a [CDATA section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution I just found that seems to work as well is using tostring() instead of write():

```
main = open('file.html', 'w')
main.write(lxml.html.tostring(htmlTree))
main.close()
```

instead of

```
htmlTree.write('file.html', pretty_print=False)
```

Figured I'd post it here as well, even though I decided to go with CDATA since it seems to be a cleaner solution that will prevent problems in the future with other parsing scripts as well.

Comment: use

`import lxml.html`