# Document type does not allow element "span" here?

Tags: validation, xhtml

I am working on getting my XHTML validated.
In my page, I have dynamic creation (in JS) of many HTML elements.
For example, I have a for loop that parses an Array that hold value's of a select tag, and then my JS code created the select with the given values. Therefore, my JS contains HTML elements inside quotes (strings). Unfortunately, I cannot get my XHTML validated because the validator things that these guys are actual elements.

How do I avoid this? Is is necessary to avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to tell the XHTML validator to parse your JavaScript different then the rest of your code. You can do this by using CDATA blocks in your script tags.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
...code...
//]]>
</script>
```

For more information for as to why, see the question [When is a CDATA section necessary within a script tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag)

Comment: thanks - this works, but causes a different issue - I have a Pyramid app that uses Chameleon for its templates. In my <script> tag inside my main HTML, I have some conditional inclusion of other scripts using Chameleon's <script tal:condition> directive. The problem is that when I add CDATA to my main <script>, Chameleon no longer recognizes its tal:condition tags. Any idea?