# W3C validator and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, w3c-validation

I'm having a lot of errors when I run W3C validator on an html page with jquery code. This is an example of the jquery code I'm using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) 
{
    /*<![CDATA[*/

    $("body").append("<div id='mainBody'>");
    $("#mainBody").append("<h1 align='center'>SCORM Authoring Tools");

    $("#mainBody").append("<table id='myTable' border='1' />");

    $("#myTable").append("<tr id='tr1' />");
    /*]]>*/
});
```

This is an example of these errors:

```
Line 4, Column 267: end tag for element "TD" which is not open
append("<td class='rows'>Product</td>");    
$("#tr1").append("<td class='rows'>…
```

I'm using `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">;` Thanks

Comment: The question is what should I do to get red of these errors? Or how to make my document valid?

Comment: It would help if you posted the errors.

Comment: This is an example of these errors: append("<td class='rows'>Product</td>"); $("#tr1").append("<td class='rows'>…

Comment: Probably not related but the `/*<![CDATA[*/` comments are unnecessary. They have no meaning in HTML.

Comment: You do not need CDATA sections when you're using an HTML 4 doctype...

Comment: This validates for me: https://gist.github.com/48f70d9921ddaaca088d I just copied/pasted your code. Did you get your `<script>` tags right?

Comment: @Ben: And it validates also without the CDATA comments (as expected).

Comment: @Felix I knew that. It's just late and I didn't bother to double-check. :) It's one reason JSON has optional escaping of the forward slash, which doesn't need to be escaped, so I can use "<\/script>". Doesn't apply to XML. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag/1450633#1450633

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't the code you pasted that's causing the issue. It's the code you didn't paste. The code below validates for me, with warnings, on http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>JS Bin</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) 
{
    /*<![CDATA[*/

    $("body").append("<div id='mainBody'>");
    $("#mainBody").append("<h1 align='center'>SCORM Authoring Tools");

    $("#mainBody").append("<table id='myTable' border='1' />");

    $("#myTable").append("<tr id='tr1' />");
    /*]]>*/
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="hello">Hello World</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I think it's probably missing or incorrect `<script>` tags.

As Felix King pointed out, you can also remove the `CDATA` comments, since you're validating with HTML rather than XML.

Comment: Ben You are right. The portion of code I posted is OK and the problem was somewhere else. Somehow I managed to solve the problem or it seems so. I removed  all close tags and amazing the validator was so happy. But I don't know in fact whether this the right way to do it.

Comment: This code didn't validate: jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
 $("body").append("<div id='mainBody'/>");
 $("#mainBody").append("<h1 align='center'>SCORM Authoring Tools</h1>");
 $("#mainBody").append("<table id='myTable' border='1'/>");
 $("#myTable").append("<tr id='tr1'/>");
 $("#tr1").append("<td class='rows'>Product</td>");
});

Comment: @FadelMS - See the first section at http://www.htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/problems.html

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to put it around all your code:

```
/*<![CDATA[*/
jQuery(document).ready(function($) 
{

    $("body").append("<div id='mainBody'>");
    $("#mainBody").append("<h1 align='center'>SCORM Authoring Tools");

    $("#mainBody").append("<table id='myTable' border='1' />");

    $("#myTable").append("<tr id='tr1' />");
});
/*]]>*/
```