# Unexpected end of file looking for </form> tag

Tags: asp.net, parse-error

i put a comment in my aspx page inside javascript  tag which said

```
//add back to <form> tag
```

And I promptly got a .NET parser error

> Unexpected end of file looking for `</form>` tag.

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.237

It's very strange that it considered a js comment as a tag... Any ideas why?

Comment: Please post the code surrounding the comment.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag) (using `//<![CDATA[
`)

Comment: That question has the info I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `<` or `>`. Use XML entities instead:

```
//add back to &lt;form&gt; tag
```

As alternative, use the asp.net comment tag:

```
<!-- // comment here -->
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like  thats an error with the .NET parser, you could try to remove the '<>' from the comment, or close the that in the same comment or in another comment. Waht abou the runat server tags ?