# Why does jslint complain when I escape the < character in a RegEx?

Tags: javascript, jslint

The code: `var foo = /\</;`

When I go to [jslint.com](http://www.jslint.com/) and enter that in, I get:

`Problem at line 1 character 12: Unexpected '\'.`

It used to tell me `Unexpected escaped character '<' in regular expression.` but times have changed.

So I'm just curious, why? If you try `var foo = /\>/;` it doesn't care, what's the deal with `<`?

Comment: There's no need to escape the "<" character there. Also JSLint is just the codification of Crockford's random opinions. Think of it as a weird dude at a bus stop complaining to you about your code.

Comment: I know there's no need to escape it, hence the error. But why that character in particular...out of all the unnecessary characters to escape, why `<`.

Comment: I'm sure there's a reason for his decision to include that warning in his application. Even if the reason is "it's stupid and confusing."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a two simple divs, the difference is clear:

```
<div> < </div> <!--Missing right angle bracket, bad markup-->
<div> > </div> <!--No problem, just a greater than text node-->
```

JSLint does not assume that the script is a standalone file or inside a script tag of an HTML document. In markup languages such as [XUL](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/xpfe/languageSpec.html), [MXML](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf61c8a-7fff.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf61c8a-7ffb), [XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750494.aspx), [TVML](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/), [LZX](http://marxsoftware.blogspot.ca/2008/05/dhtmlswf-differences-in-openlaszlo.html), [XHTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-xhtml-syntax.html#xml-fragment-parsing-algorithm) or [SVG](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/script.html#ScriptElement), the script tag content is treated like the first div in the above example, so the left angle bracket will look like the start of a tag. In those languages, use an entity replacement or a CDATA block to wrap the left angle bracket and ampersand characters:

```
<script> 
if ( -1 &lt; 0 &amp;&amp; true !== false) {} 
</script>

<script>
<![CDATA[
if ( -2 < 0 && true !== false) {}
]]>
</script>
```

**References**

- [Escaped Markup Considered Harmful](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/08/20/embedded.html)