# HTML validation / script JS

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm having a little problem to validate a html page with a js script.

i have this js part : " .

> var lastPage = this.getNumPages() - 1;
>
> if (this.displayedPage < lastPage)
>
> nextPageLink.css('visibility', 'visible');

Everything works fine but i have 1 error remaining when i try to validate it:

> > > Line 856, Column 30: character  is the first character of a delimiter but occurred as data
> > >       if (this.displayedPage < lastPage)
> > >
> > > ✉ This message may appear in several cases:
> > >       You tried to include the "<" character in your page: you should escape it as "<"
> > >       You used an unescaped ampersand "&": this may be valid in some contexts, but it is recommended to use "&", which is always safe.
> > >       Another possibility is that you forgot to close quotes in a previous tag.
> > >
> > > Line 856, Column 30: StartTag: invalid element name
> > >                               if (this.displayedPage < lastPage)

I just want a way to replace the < sign with something that works whit my script and will pass the W3C validation.

Comment: Remember that validation isn't as important as you may think.  They often want to do some extra footwork that really isn't necessary.  I suspect something like that is going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare your JavaScript as cdata. The < symbol is interpreted as part of a tag, causing the error.

[When is a CDATA section necessary within a script tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `<script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>` to load your javascript file instead of putting it in your htmle file.