# Content of elements must consist of well-formed mark-up

Tags: javascript

So I was asking a question on here, got around to implementing the solution, and it doesn't seem to work particularly well - I keep getting the error "content of elements must consiste of well-formed mark-up"

I am using the NetBeans IDE.

It seems to center around the < before len

Here's the code that brings up this error:

```
function formValidation() {

var ids = ["orgname", "cultpicklist", "catpicklist", "servpicklist"],
    formValue = 1;

for (var i = 0, len = ids.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (document.getElementById(ids[i]).value === "") {
       formValue = 0;
       break;
    }

 if (formValue == 1) {
           return true;
      } else if (formValue == 0) {
           alert('Please fill out all required fields');
           return false;
      }
}
```

Comment: where are you getting the error?

Comment: formOkay is not defined.

Comment: @danihp it could be in a larger scope.

Comment: missing a closing bracket as well

Comment: i would assume that `content of elements must consiste of well-formed mark-up` is not javascript related but somewhere else.

Comment: Closing bracket added, and formOkay switched to formValue throughout. Also put it in CDATA tags, and still it does not give an alert when one of the fields is not filled in.

Comment: content of elements... seems to have been a CDATA issue. Code still not working, however.

Comment: javascript runtime or whatever that is running your javascript code has interpreted that <len is a tag. You should check that all code (before and after your script) is "well-formed mark-up" or follow @MДΓΓБДLL answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Does this piece of JavaScript happen to live in a `<script>` tag in an XHTML page? If so, move it to an external JS file, or [use a `CDATA` section in the script tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag).