# Modify JavaScript to exclude first column from opening new page

Tags: javascript

I have a html table with data. I use this JavaScript to open new page when I click on a table row:

```
function addOnclickToDatatableRows() {
                //gets all the generated rows in the html table
                var trs = document.getElementById('form:dataTable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]
                .getElementsByTagName('tr');
                //on every row, add onclick function (this is what you're looking for)
                for (var i = 0; trs.length > i; i++) {
                    trs[i].onclick = new Function("rowOnclick(this)");
                }
            }

            function rowOnclick(tr) {
                var elements = tr.cells[0].childNodes;
                for(var i = 0; elements.length > i; i++) {
                    if ((typeof elements[i].id !== "undefined") &amp;&amp;
                    (elements[i].id.indexOf("lnkHidden") > -1)) {
                        //opne in a new window//  window.open(elements[i].href);
                        location.href=elements[i].href
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
```

How I can modify the script to exclude the first column when I click on a row. On the first column of the table I have checkboxes which I don't want to click and open a new page

Best wishes

Answer (score 2):

You could do a couple of things:

If you want to keep using the script you provided you could set the onclick on the td's instead of the tr's and skip the first one. You'll have to write the part between ... yourself, but that should no be hard

```
function addOnclickToDatatableRows() {
  //gets all the generated rows in the html table
  var trs = document.getElementById('form:dataTable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');
  //on every row, add onclick function (this is what you're looking for)
  for (var i = 0; trs.length > i; i++) {
     var tds = trs[i].getElementsByTagName('td');        
     for (var j = 1; j <= tds.length; j++) {
       tds[j].onclick = new Function("colOnclick(this)");
     }
  }
}

function colOnclick(td) {
  var link = ...get the link from the tr using parentNode...
  location.href=link
  return false;
}
```

I would however change the html and the javascript like this:

1. Put the link you want to open when clicking on the row in a `data-` attribute of the `TR` tag. (e.g. `<tr data-link="http://www.link.com")>`
2. Use only one onclick handler: put it on the table itself
3. I the click handler figure out the target:

   ```
   function handler(e) {

     var targ;
     if (!e) var e = window.event;
     if (e.target) targ = e.target;
     else if (e.srcElement) targ = e.srcElement;

     do stuff with targ...
   }
   ```
4. If the target is inside the first td or a tr ignore it. Otherwise determine the tr the target is inside in, get the data-link attribute and open it.

I'd also use jQuery or something similar to do the heavy lifting. In that case it's much easier. The only code you need is this:

The HTML:

```
<table id="idOfTable">
    <tr data-link="http://www.ledlamp.nl">
        <td>col1</td>
        <td>col2</td>
        <td>col3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-link="http://www.isaac.nl">
        <td>col1</td>
        <td>col2</td>
        <td>col3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The jQuery
​

```
$('#idOfTable').delegate('td:gt(0)', 'click', function() { 
   document.location.href = $(this).closest('tr').data('link')
});​
```

In it I select the table you want to handle all clicks of. Only clicked elements that match the CSS3 selector `td:gt(0)` will be listened to. (This selector returns all td's that are not the first one.). When clicked it finds the closest TR (its TR parent) and gets the data-link attribute using the `.data()` function. As you can see jQuery can be very powerful in one a few lines of code.

I created a jsfiddle example for you. Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/TDjhT/

Comment: How I can simplify the JavaScript? Is there other more simple solution?

Comment: Yes, use jquery. Do you know how to?

Comment: I changed my answer. It contains the jQuery version at the bottom now. You only need to include jQuery and the script will work. http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery

Comment: Unfortunately I failed to properly write the JavaScript code. I know too little JavaScript. This is the code where I managed to write. Would you help with the code, please? http://pastebin.com/u3fj6sLw