# Site's template changes when iPad uses access it

Tags: html, ipad, browser

A quick question, How do I change to my 'iPad.html' page by detecting what browser or device that person is using.

Some one told me that this is the solution :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> // <![CDATA[
    if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad') != -1)) {
        document.location = "http://www.mysite.com/ipad.html";
    } // ]]>
</script>
```

I just want to make sure that this is right.

Comment: Believe it or not, some people out there don't have an iPad.

Comment: I don't have an iPad!!! That's why I'm asking!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work, but you should use the more standard `window.location`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad') != -1)) {
        window.location.href = "http://www.mysite.com/ipad.html";
    }
</script>
```

`CDATA` comments [are not necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag), since nobody uses XML these days. (Or do you?)