# Custom JavaScript Creating Random Characters in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am working on a problem that a client has come across, the javascript that they are using is causing a `/*` and `/*]]>*/` to show up on the Login Tooltip. I have been looking for the cause and I am baffled by it. All I know is that it is being generated somehow by the JavaScript at [This Page](http://www.apistudyabroad.com).

The plugin is using this template which doesn't have any of those characters in it:

```
<script type="text/template" id="api-login-btn-template">
    <div id="api-signin">
        <label for="api-signin-login">Login : </label><input type="text" id="api-signin-login" name="email" value="" title="e-mail address"/>
        <label for="api-signin-pass">Password : </label><input type="password" id="api-signin-pass" name="password" value="" title="password"/>
        <div class="sign-in-errors"></div>
        <br/>
        <button class="sign-in-btn"><span>Sign In</span> <span class="blue">&#x25B6;</span></button>
    </div>
    <div id="api-signout" style="display:none">
        <p><a href="/program-finder/favorites/">My Favorite Programs <span  class="ltblue_link">&#x25B6;</span></a></p>
        <p>Application: <a id="api-app-status" href="https://secure.apistudyabroad.com/forms"></a></p>
        <button class="sign-out-btn"><span>Sign Out</span></button>
    </div>
</script>
```

The javascript file responsible for this feature is [here](http://www.apistudyabroad.com/wp-content/plugins/api_js/js/api.js). I believe the pop up starts at Line 400 with `$('.pane-container').each(function() {`

Comment: It's happening in both chrome and firefox for me.

Comment: Hmmmmm thanks, I cleared my browser cache and sure enough it showed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how your template looks like on generated page (view source in Firefox):

```
<script type="text/template" id="find-a-program-template">
/*<![CDATA[*/<div style="padding:20px;"><h2> 
...
...
...<div class="clear"></div></div>/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Seems like PHP / WordPress adds that CDATA part to the template during page rendering, but jQuery plugin doesn't know how to ignore it and writes it down instead.

Btw, you also have a bunch of server side `<?php the_time('m') ?>` calls on the page, but that's probably unrelated.

Comment: Hmmmm they are using w3 Total Cache plugin, do you think that could be where it is adding it?

Comment: Not really sure... I didn't work with WP. PHP, or WordPress is trying to be a good XHTML citizen and embeds the script tag content in CDATA - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag jQuery plugin that parses the template should really ignore that CDATA... Maybe you could replace it with something else?

Comment: Ahhhh I see, so because it is a script tag and has HTML within it, it is handling it as an xml excerpt essentially?

Comment: Thanks, that will help me figure out what to do about that. Who figured lol.