# I can't read the code from XML file

Tags: php, xml, xmldom

I've saved javascript code in xml file.
but when I get it show as empty xml tag.

**The XML Code**

```
<ad>
  <Name> Ad 1 </Name>
  <place> 1 </place>
  <Type> code </Type>
  <content>
     <script type="text/javascript">
      <!--
        google_ad_client = "pub-*********";
        /* 160x600, 28/08/09 */
        google_ad_slot = "*********";
        google_ad_width = 160;
        google_ad_height = 600;
      //-->
     </script>
     <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
     </script>
  </content>
</ad>
```

When I get the tag `content` by using PHP DOMDocument I find it empty, 
and when I checked the page source code, I find it empty no javascript exists.
Although when I bring the value of another tag like `Name`,`Type`, displays without problems.
I have no doubt in PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is invalid.

Quotes must be `&quot;` and so on, in your JavaScript.  If you don't want to do that, it must be wrapped in a CDATA block.

```
<script>
<![CDATA[
    ...code...
]]>
</script>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66900/362536

Comment: Thanks, I find in the page source code this part of code only `<!--
                google_ad_client = "pub-********";
                /* 160x600, 28/08/09 */
                google_ad_slot = "********";
                google_ad_width = 160;
                google_ad_height = 600;
                //-->` But the rest of the code does not appear

Comment: @LionKing, I don't know what you are asking at this point.  You said you had trouble parsing XML.  I explained why.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is we must add `<![CDATA[` before all javascript and `]]>` after all javascript like the following:

```
<![CDATA[
    <script type="text/javascript">
     <!--
     google_ad_client = "pub-***********";
     /* 160x600, 28/08/09 */
     google_ad_slot = "-***********"";
     google_ad_width = 160;
     google_ad_height = 600;
     //-->          
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
   </script>
]]>
```

The final form is as the following:

```
<ad>
  <Name> Ad 1 </Name>
  <place> 1 </place>
  <Type> code </Type>
  <content>
   <![CDATA[
     <script type="text/javascript">
      <!--
        google_ad_client = "pub-*********";
        /* 160x600, 28/08/09 */
        google_ad_slot = "*********";
        google_ad_width = 160;
        google_ad_height = 600;
      //-->
     </script>
     <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
     </script>
    ]]>
  </content>
</ad>
```