# How to decode HTML entities for XHTML application

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml, decode

How to decode HTML entities for XHTML application?

For example, `$("<div/>").html("&middot;").text()` will raise an JavaScript error.

Error is:

> `[Exception... "An invalid or illegal string was specified" code: "12" nsresult: "0x8053000c (SyntaxError)"`

**EDIT: XHTML means real XHTML application, with `application/xhtml+xml` Content-type.**

Comment: That gives a JavaScript error? Can you provide a jsFiddle example that shows the error? I can't produce one with that code.

Comment: AFAIK, jsfiddle HTML, not XHTML.

Comment: I'm using jsBin, with an XHTML doctype, and I can't get the error. http://jsbin.com/ivisef/1/edit

Comment: please check content-type. it's text/html

Comment: I understand what you mean now.

Comment: I'm not as familiar with XHTML. Does wrapping the code win CDATA tags help, or is this a different issue? http://stackoverflow.com/a/66865/1689607

Comment: no, CDATA will preserve decoding entity. I need decoding HTML entity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `document.createEntityReference` or escape the characters unsuitable for your file encoding at JavaScript code's level (`\uxxxx`); but, as pointed in your comment, `document.createEntityReference` doesn't work on Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/document.createEntityReference

Alternatively, you can use a custom library such as php.js's `html_entity_decode`: http://phpjs.org/functions/html_entity_decode/

Comment: document.createEntityReference doesn't work in Fx neither Chrome. Looks like deprecated yet. \x26middot; also doesn't work.

Comment: @AlexIvasyuv: Unicode escape sequences in JS don't work with reference names; you have to get the corresponding code point first.

Comment: Using html_entity_decode with http://phpjs.org/functions/get_html_translation_table/ works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Try using pure-JavaScript [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML) property instead of jQuery's `html()` method:

```js
var elem = document.createElement('div');
elem.innerHTML = '&middot;';

var text = $(elem).text();

alert(text);
```

If jQuery has issues with XHTML, you can try to avoid it completely. Instead of `jQuery.text()`, [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent) property can be used (for obsolete versions of IE, `innerText` can be used).

In general, it makes sense to decode entities on server side. For example, in PHP, there is a standard function for this purpose: [`html_entity_decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php).

Comment: Did you try your example in XHTML application?

Comment: I've tried in HTML page (there is no point to use XHTML [with `application/xhtml+xml` Content-Type] today).

Comment: BTW, why not to switch to regular HTML?