# document type does not allow element "span" here

Tags: jquery, html

In part of a jquery code I have this line of code below:

```
 var newHtml="<span style='color: green'>"+result.msg+"</span>"
```

Now the jquery code is displayed in the `<body>` section but the problem is that I am getting an error in my validation stating:

> document type does not allow element "span" here

My question is that is there a way to fix it while keeping the span tag or do I need to use an alternative?

Full code form the View source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Edit Assessment Date/Start Time</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="edit_sessionadminStyles.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/ui-lightness/jquery.ui.timepicker.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.ui.timepicker.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>

        </head>
        <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">


     function submitform() {    

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "updatedatetime.php",
            data: $('#updateForm').serialize(),
            dataType:'json',  //get response as json
            success: function(result){
                        if(result.errorflag){

           //do your stuff on getting error message
          var newHtml="<span class='red'>"+result.msg+"</span>"; 
          $("#targetdiv").html(newHtml);  //i am displaying the error msg here

        }else{
           //you got success message

           var newHtml="<span class='green'>"+result.msg+"</span>"; 
                $("#targetdiv").html(newHtml);
                //Get and store the new date and time.
                    var newDate = jQuery("#newDate").val();
                    var newTime = jQuery("#newTime").val();

                    //Set your current date and time to your new date and time.
                    jQuery("#currentDate").val(newDate);
                    jQuery("#currentTime").val(newTime);

                    //Find the currently selected session and update it.
                    var selectedOption = jQuery("#sessionsDrop option:selected");
                    var label = selectedOption.text().split(" - ");
                    selectedOption.text(label[0] + " - " + newDate + " - " + newTime);

                    //Clear the new date and time fields.
                    jQuery("#newDate").val("");
                    jQuery("#newTime").val("");

                    $('#targetdiv').show();
            }
        }
      });        
    }



    $('body').on('click', '#updateSubmit', showConfirm);       


    </script>   

   <noscript style='color: red'><img src="Images/warning-2.fw.png" alt="Javascript Warning" id="warningImage" name="warningSymbol"/> In order to use this application without any problems, you must have javascript enabled</noscript>
Please Login to Access this Page | <a href='./adminlogin.php'>Login</a>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with Span inside the <head> section?

Comment: Maybe wrap the code in cdata or comments

Comment: post you code of html file

Comment: Im using ajax and jquery to navigate to another script where it perform a query and then it displays echo's on success or fail depending on situation, then I use the code above to be able to display the message on the main page. I have always put my ajax and jquery/javascript code in the head section

Comment: well, it should be there!

Comment: Sorry guys it is in the body section not head section. Sorry bout this

Comment: use below code end <span> with `<//span>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Scenario 1 : when span is in `<Head>` tag**

You have to use `CDATA`like below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
...code...
//]]>
</script>
```

Check for more information [**When is a CDATA section necessary within a script tag?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag)

**Scenario 2: when span is in `<Body>` tag**

```
<body>
   <div></div>

<script>
   $("div").html("<span class='red'>Hello <b>Again</b></span>");
</script>

</body>
```

**EDIT**

Your problem may be this:you have to put `errorflag` for `msg`

**Your code (wrong)**

```
if(result.errorflag){

           //do your stuff on getting error message
          var newHtml="<span class='red'>"+result.msg+"</span>"; 
          $("#targetdiv").html(newHtml);  //i am displaying the error msg here
```

**Corrected one:**

```
 if(result.errorflag){

               //do your stuff on getting error message
              var newHtml="<span class='red'>"+result.errorflag+"</span>"; 
              $("#targetdiv").html(newHtml);  //i am displaying the error msg here
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Sorry guys it is in the body section not head section. Sorry bout this

Comment: @user1830984 Try to use like above scenario 2.

Comment: @user1830984 can you check the value of "result.msg" using fire bug??

Comment: Which tab in firebug to I go on to check this?

Comment: @user1830984 "script" Tab after that reload the page then put a brake point on the place where you want to debug.

Comment: @user1830984 here are some good articles about java script debugger http://getfirebug.com/javascript and http://www.developerfusion.com/article/139949/debugging-javascript-with-firebug/

Comment: tested it with firebug, there isn't any errors displayed in firebug, the breakpoint displays a golden arrow after the message appears (well would appear if I did not stop the break point at that point)

Comment: @user1830984 check my EDIT Part above

Comment: This won't be the problem, the message works well, its just the validation which is the problem, its got to be the <span> tag which is causing the problem

Comment: @user1830984 But other than that I couldn't see any issue about the span tag.You put that in correct way.That is the way it should be.May be just try to put div element there and check.Then you can identify the real issue.try that.Remove span and as a test put div element there.

Comment: I will mark your answer because of your effort, the javascript is working so I don't think I have to worry about the validator as I think that is only for proper html.

Comment: @user1830984 what happened when you changed it to div?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. The `<head>` isn't displayed so a visual element like a `<span>` has no meaning there.

Comment: Sorry guys it is in the body section not head section. Sorry bout this

Answer (score 0):

hey use this code it will help you

```
var newHtml="<span class='red'>"+result.msg+"<//span>";
```

Answer (score 0):

`span` is an inline element and needs a surrounding block-element. just try to use a `div` instead of your span. this should fix the validation error.

Answer (score 0):

By XHTML rules, `script` element content is parsed for HTML tags, and `script` elements must not contain any tags. There are various ways around this, including a switch to HTML 4.01 (or HTML5). If you keep using XHTML 1.0, then the [recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_4) in the spec is: “Use external scripts if your script uses <”. That is, replace the `script` containing script code by a `link` element that refers to that code written in an external .js file.