# Syntax error while trying to add CDATA within script tags dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cdata

So there is an ad code which I try to add to the DOM dynamically, something that looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--<![CDATA[
   JAVASCRIPT CODE
//]]>--></script>
```

If I paste this code directly in the source code, it works, but if I try to insert it to the DOM with jQuery it throws some untraceable errors - at least I cant trace it. Actually this:

[image: javascript syntax error]

The interesting part is that Firebug connects this error to random scripts in the page which contain jQuery. The ad code is inserted into the DOM this way /`element` is a jQuery object/:

```
element.html(data.content);
```

What I have tried yet:

1. I have tried to remove the `<!-- -->` html comment tags.
2. I have tried to wrap the wole code to a script tag dynamically created by jQuery.
3. I even tried to remove the CDATA tags, but that broke everything, I think it is important for the main ad handler script provided by the ad manager company.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

(Please dont care about the method, it must be done with ajax.)

**EDIT:** The problem still persists, but I think there must be a problem with the ad code, so I accepted the first useful answer for this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
        ...
//]]>
</script>

<!-- (For styles, it is different) -->

<style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
        ...
/*]]>*/
</style>
```

And if you really need compatibility with very old browsers that do not recognize the script or style tags resulting in their contents displayed on the page, you can use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
        ...
//--><!]]></script>

<!-- (For styles, it is different) -->

<style type="text/css"><!--/*--><![CDATA[/*><!--*/
        ...
/*]]>*/--></style>
```

With `<![CDATA[` you can embed `JS` in `XML` (and XHTML) documents without the need to replace special `XML` characters like `<`, `>`, `&`, etc by XML entities `<`, `>`, `&` etc

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
  ...
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Comment: + For the reason the `<![CDATA[` is commented out:
+ > In this case, the HTML parser is used,  which does treat the script contents as CDATA automatically,  so the `<![CDATA[` and `]]>`.  become part of the script to be run by the JavaScript engine. 
+ > Therefore,  to hide those strings from the JavaScript engine,  they are preceded with `//` on the same line,  which means that  the JavaScript engine thinks the lines are comments.
+ [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382434/why-does-cdata-is-commented-out-under-script-tags)

Comment: [^ continue]
+ > When browsers treat the markup as HTML and you want your XHTML 1.0 markup (for example) to validate.
+ [ref-more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag)

Answer (score 0):

Use this one

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 //<![CDATA[
 //YOUR CODE
//]]>
</script>
```

Let me know if problem still persist.