# Why does CDATA is commented out under script tags ?

Tags: asp.net, html, cdata

*I was reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092236/what-is-cdata-in-html) and I have a related question :*

This guy [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7092256/859154) said that :

> It is used in script tags to avoid parsing < and &. In HTML, this is
>   not needed, because in HTML, script is **already** #CDATA.

<kbd>Question #1</kbd>

If SCRIPT is *already* #CDATA  : why does it renderd (under script tag) still as CDATA ?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
// <![CDATA[

// ]]>
</script>
```

<kbd>Question #2</kbd>

And why is it as a comment ? (`//`)

Comment: It's commented out because otherwise you'd get a JS syntax error. I don't see CDATA being used much in HTML script tags these days and don't use it myself. Maybe it's from the days of XHTML, because CDATA is an XML construct and XHTML used many of XML's rules.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

XHTML is supposed to be served as XML by using media type `application/xhtml+xml`. In HTML5, the markup is **only** XHTML if it is served with an XML media type. When served like this, the contents of script elements are **not** CDATA.

So to get the XML parser to treat the script contents as CDATA, they can be wrapped in `<![CDATA[ ]]>`.

While few people have historically served markup as `application/xhtml+xml`, many have validated their pages as if it was XHTML. The XHTML validator equally expects that the script contents are not ordinarily CDATA, and so will typically reject tags and other scraps of markup embedded in the JavaScript, unless they are escaped with `<![CDATA[ ]]>`

Having validated their pages as XHTML, they'd then serve their pages with a `text/html` media type to browsers, which meant that the browser treats the markup as HTML, not XHTML. In this case, the HTML parser is used, which *does* treat the script contents as CDATA automatically, so the `<![CDATA[` and `]]>`. become part of the script to be run by the JavaScript engine. Therefore, to hide those strings from the JavaScript engine, they are preceded with `//` on the same line, which means that the JavaScript engine thinks the lines are comments.

Finally, some people serve the same markup as both `application/xhtml+xml` and `text/html`, switching based on the information found in the HTTP request message. For the same reasons as above, to get the script contents to be processed correctly in both modes, the  `//<![CDATA[` and `//]]>` pattern is a very effective technique.

Comment: I think the key point here is that XML comments start with "<!--" and end with "-->", while JavaScript comments start with "/*" and end with "*/" or start with "//" and end with carriage return or newline. So in effect these lines are commented out in JavaScript but not in XML. Therefore the XML engine still recognizes the "<![CDATA[" and "]]>" and lets them work as normal, escaping otherwise reserved characters that might appear in the JS (as Alohci explained well). It's one of those weird gems of coolness :D