# External link validation in XHTML

Tags: xhtml

I've posted this question in [another post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36073313/validation-in-xhtml) but nobody answered it despite answering the other question I've posted with it.
I have external links in the 'source' section in the XHTML Transition document:

```
<p class="source">AARON. "Grandmasters of Flash: An Interview with the Creators of Flash | Cold Hard Flash: <br/>
            <span class="tab">Flash Animation News, Videos and Links." <i>Cold Hard Flash Flash Animation News</i> </span> <br/>
            <span class="tab"><i>Videos and Links RSS</i>. N.p., 12 Feb. 2008. Web.</span> <br/>
            <span class="tab">&lt;<a href="http://www.coldhardflash.com/2008/02/grandmasters-of-flash-an-interview-with-the-creators-of-flash.html" target="_blank">http://www.coldhardflash.com/2008/02/grandmasters-of-flash-an-interview-with-the-creators-of-flash.html</a>.&gt;</span>
        </p>

        <p class="source">Boulton, Jim. "Macromedia Flash Back." <i>Digital Archaeology</i>. WordPress, 05 Sept. 2012. Web. <br/>
            <span class="tab">&lt;<a href="http://digital-archaeology.org/flash-back/" target="_blank">http://digital-archaeology.org/flash-back/</a>.&gt;</span>
        </p>

        <p class="source">Clover, Juli. "Adobe Renaming 'Flash Professional' to 'Animate', Shifts Focus to HTML5." - <br/>
            <span class="tab"><i>Mac Rumors</i>. MacRumors, 01 Dec. 2015. Web.</span> <br/>
            <span class="tab">&lt;<a href="http://www.macrumors.com/2015/12/01/adobe-renames-flash-professional-to-animate/" target="_blank">http://www.macrumors.com/2015/12/01/adobe-renames-flash-professional-to-animate/</a>.&gt;</span>
        </p>

        <p class="source">Dalrymple, Jim. "Adobe, Macromedia Reach Agreement in Patent Lawsuit." <i>Macworld</i>. IDG  <br/>
            <span class="tab">Consumer &amp; SMB, 29 July 2002. Web.</span> <br/>
            <span class="tab">&lt;<a href="http://www.macworld.com/article/1008577/lawsuit.html" target="_blank">http://www.macworld.com/article/1008577/lawsuit.html</a>.&gt;</span>
        </p>

        <p class="source">Lardinois, Frederic. "Adobe Launches Animate CC, Previously Known As <br/>
            <span class="tab">Flash Professional." <i>TechCrunch</i>. AOL Inc., 08 Feb. 2016. Web.</span> <br/>
            <span class="tab">&lt;<a href="http://techcrunch.com/2016/02/08/adobe-launches-animate-cc-previously-known-as-flash-professional/" target="_blank">http://techcrunch.com/2016/02/08/adobe-launches-animate-cc-previously-known-as-flash-professional/</a>.&gt;</span>
        </p>

        <p class="source">Lee, Rich. "Welcome Adobe Animate CC, a New Era for Flash Professional." <i>Adobe Animate</i> <br/>
            <span class="tab"><i>Team Blog</i>. Adobe Systems Incorporated, 30 Nov. 2015. Web.</span> <br/>
            <span class="tab">&lt;<a href="http://blogs.adobe.com/animate/welcome-adobe-animate-cc-a-new-era-for-flash-professional/?sdid=JRSIQ&mv=search&s_kwcid=AL!3085!3!91748895283!e!!g!!flash%20professional&ef_id=Vut2uAAAAVolsjfr:20160318054023:ss" target="_blank">http://blogs.adobe.com/animate/welcome-adobe-animate-cc-a-new-era-for-flash-professional/?sdid=JRSIQ&mv=search&s_kwcid=AL!3085!3!91748895283!e!!g!!flash%20professional&ef_id=Vut2uAAAAVolsjfr:20160318054023:ss</a>.&gt;</span>
        </p>

        <p class="source">Rouse, Margaret. "ActonScript: What Is ActionScript? - Definition from <br/>
            <span class="tab">WhatIs.com." <i>SearchSOA</i>. TechTarget, Sept. 2005. Web.</span> <br/>
            <span class="tab">&lt;<a href="http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/definition/ActionScript" target="_blank">http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/definition/ActionScript</a>.&gt;</span>
        </p>

        <p class="source">Waldron, Rick. "The Flash History." <i>Flashmagazine.com</i>. Digiguru, 20 Nov. 2000. Web. <br/>
            <span class="tab">&lt;<a href="http://www.flashmagazine.com/news/detail/the_flash_history/" target="_blank">http://www.flashmagazine.com/news/detail/the_flash_history/</a>.&gt;</span>
        </p>
```

They won't pass despite other external links passing. 
[image]

Comment: Oh well, I answered. But like was commented to the other question, your XHTML document is not really XHTML. Therefore, the solution to all the validation problems is to use the HTML5 doctype rather than XHTML 1.0 Transitional.

Comment: The error message tells you what the problem is and how to fix it! https://www.evernote.com/l/AAPOA2C6W6dMXIN2Oc87RU2hxtxvuDEXJtI

Comment: The reason nobody answered on the other question was because it was a *different* question that you appended to the first question *after* you had received an answer to the first question!

Answer (score -1):

To validate something as XHTML, it must be well-formed XML. So all ampersands, even the ones in attribute values, must be escaped. For example,

```
... professional/?sdid=JRSIQ&mv=search ...
```

should be written as

```
... professional/?sdid=JRSIQ&amp;mv=search ...
```

Otherwise, the validator will think that you're using an entity `&mv`, which doesn't exist. Hence the error.

Edit: in contrast to what other answers are saying, `&amp;` is a valid XML entity name; see the [official definition of XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-predefined-ent). The other answer may be confused with entities such as `&eacute;` or `&nbsp;` which are valid in HTML, but not in XHTML.

Answer (score -1):

Use numeric HTML entities such as `&#38;` for ampersands for *both* the HTML and XML parsers instead of `&amp;` which are *not* valid entities. The [December](http://www.december.com/html/spec/codes.html) website has a fairly exhaustive list and I'd also highly recommend the [Unicode Character Table](http://unicode-table.com/en/) website.

My platform and website (link in my profile) is served as XHTML5 and utilizes UTF8 characters in place of images (fewer HTTP requests for better performance) so if you're looking for a fully fledged example of an XHTML5 website you'll find it linked in my profile.

I don't live here on SO though I'll poke around and try to give positive support for certain tags especially since so many people are negative when it comes to XHTML5. Have any more questions just comment. :-)