# Strange error using comments in a <script> tag when page is saved (and used) as .ASP

Tags: javascript, comments

I am dealing with old Javascript scripts which are still using comments to hide JS code from browsers that do not support or blocked it. I know that **it is not a best practice anymore**, anyway it should not cause any harm (there are still many pages on Internet which implement this code).

But I get an error when running this code:

```
<video id="player"></video>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function pop(){ document.getElementById("player").onloadedmetadata=null}
//-->
</script>

<div onclick="pop()">Click here</div>
```

When clicking on "click here", Chrome and Firefox **throw an error** telling that "pop" is not defined.

If I remove the line with "**<!--**", the script runs correctly.

Can you explain me this behavior? Thanks

**EDIT:** it turns out that this happens if a page is saved with a .ASP extension (Classic ASP), while renaming it as .HTM there is no error! There must be some sort of conflict between JS and the ASP interpreter...

**EDIT 2:** I know how to add a comment in a Javascript block and I don't need info on this. The "<!--" line inside a block script is still perfectly valid even if outdated (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-can-javascript-code-be-hidden-from-old-browsers-that-do-not-support-javascript). I'd just like to know why this script is causing an error if inserted into an .ASP page. Thanks

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/1wzbgrny/

Comment: Just don't use HTML comment marks in JS, use regular `//` or `/* */` instead.

Comment: I have many pages using this old-style way to hide javascript if not supported by a browser (see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Are-HTML-comments-inside-script-tags-a-best-practice). Obviously I don't use this method anymore. The strange thing is that the error happens only if a page is interpreted by the MS ASP engine.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16382434/1169519) ..?