# unescaped & or unknown entity "&&" javascript

Tags: javascript, entity

This is part of my homework but i can't figure out what is wrong and any help would be appreciated

```
var InputNum = prompt("Please enter a number between 50 and 100:", "");
if (isNaN(InputNum)) {
    if (InputNum.match(/one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten/)) {
        alert("while this is a number, it's not really a number to me.");
    } else {
        alert(InputNum + " doesn't appear to be a number.");
    }
} else if (InputNum >= 99 && InputNum <= 51); {
    alert("theat number, " + inputNum + ", is not between 50 and 100.");
}
document.write("The user gave a number in the range! " + inputNum + "<br>");
```

on line 25 it comes up with the warning that the title states.

Comment: How do you incorporate this script on the page?

Comment: `InputNum >= 99 && InputNum <= 51` - Greater than (or equal to) 99 AND less than (or equal to) 51?

Comment: You must be using an XHTML doctype. In that case, either use an HTML5 doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html>`), escape the ampersands (`&amp;`), or [put the script block in a `CDATA` section](http://stackoverflow.com/q/66837/139010).

Comment: I'm not sure my teacher gave us three different problems to debug and I did the other two and all of the only instructions for this was "debug - If statements get a number in a specific range from the user."

Comment: I notice you also seem to have a stray `;` after the `else if (InputNum >= 99 && InputNum <= 51)`... that probably should not be there, and will cause the `else if` block to be skipped I believe.

Comment: @MattBall tbh there is `document.write` so html is the only option

Comment: @Jacedc Thank you i should have seen that

Answer (score 8):

The character `&` in HTML is reserved for entities, such as `&nbsp;` and `&quot;`. This error is complaining about `&` being misused; it is a sign you should write it as `&amp;` (which is the correct entity for the `&` symbol), or you should put your script in a context where it is not interpreted as HTML (such as CDATA).

Comment: wonder if he is using Tidy? A quick search shows the same error http://www.htmlpedia.org/wiki/Tidy_3

Comment: I have since figured out a way to fix my issue thank you for all the help, it was a combination of all your answers.