# CDATA being added automatically on JS in Yii?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, yii

I am coding in Yii and whenever I put any JS it tags it in CDATA.

Why is it getting added automatically? and will there be any problem if I remove it as I write my markup in HTML5.

Comment: cdata tags are necessary if you're putting scripts into pure XML, but are not necessary for HTML5.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag

Comment: The thing is the framework Yii automatically adds it.. So will it interfere with HTML5?

Comment: @SankalpSingha no it won't. CDATA are harmless in html, including html5.

Answer (score 1):

Like what arnaud said in the comment if the question, it wont affect your html 5 code. So its okay.

In addition, cdata tags are quite necessary to be used for scripts in XML, so its actually a feature from Yii.

Comment: Experiment by toggling the compatibility mode in IE. This should solve the issue.