# Javascript embedded in html and greater / less than signs

Tags: javascript, html

Long time ago I faced a problem with embedding too much JavaScript inside the html page in `<script>` tags.  The JavaScript had lots of `<` and `>` signs and it was somehow conflicting with the actual page html tags.

I am now unable to recreate this.  How can this possibly happen?  Or are the browsers now a bit more intelligent in handling embedded JavasSript?

Comment: You might find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag enlightening (discussion about HTML, XHTML, embedded JavaScript, and CDATA guard).

Comment: No, it was always allowed to use `<script>` tags in `HTML` without any conflicts, I think you must have done something wrong.

Comment: @SheikhHeera: He's talking about an error when `<script> old = age < 18 </script>` throws syntax error because `<` in `age < 18` is taken as opening of a tag - not the `<` and `>` surrounding `script`.

Comment: @Amadan, Oops! Got it wrong!

Comment: In modern browsers, if HTML, `<` within scripts will cause no problem. If XHTML, it will, and needs to be CDATA'd or escaped as `&lt;`. In any case, it's better to externalize scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this issue, however, not in a browser , but in an IDE - JBoss Developer Studio (which is a variant of Eclipse IDE)

[image]

When i run the application in the browser (its a Java Enterprise application, running on JBoss web server), i get the same error as in the IDE : The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup. While modern browsers have solved this issue, embedding javascript code in a JSF page (Java Server Faces) , as i did, still hits the same problem. Perhaps you might want to give it a try: create a simple JSF application, embed the javascript, run it on a Java web server like JBoss