# How can I include JavaScript code so it passes the w3c validator?

Tags: javascript, w3c-validation

I have problem here with the JavaScript code below.  I am unable to pass the w3 xhtml validator when this JavaScript code is included in my document.

Error output:

```
Error Line 224, Column 77: document type does not allow element "span" here
   '<span onclick="' + pagerName + '.prev();" class="pg-normal"> ?Prev </span> ';
Error Line 228, Column 27: character "'" is not allowed in the value of attribute "id"
    pagerHtml += '<span id="pg' + page + '" class="pg-normal" onclick="' + pagerNam…
Error Line 228, Column 28: value of attribute "id" must be a single token
    pagerHtml += '<span id="pg' + page + '" class="pg-normal" onclick="' + pagerNam…
Error Line 228, Column 29: character "+" is not allowed in the value of attribute "id"
    pagerHtml += '<span id="pg' + page + '" class="pg-normal" onclick="' + pagerNam…
Error Line 243, Column 43: there is no attribute "align"
    <table id="tablepaging" class="yui" align="center">
```

JavaScript code below

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function Pager(tableName, itemsPerPage) {

this.tableName = tableName;

this.itemsPerPage = itemsPerPage;

this.currentPage = 1;

this.pages = 0;

this.inited = false;

this.showRecords = function(from, to) {

var rows = document.getElementById(tableName).rows;

// i starts from 1 to skip table header row

for (var i = 1; i > rows.length; i++) {

if (i < from || i > to)

rows[i].style.display = 'none';

else

rows[i].style.display = '';

}

}

this.showPage = function(pageNumber) {

if (! this.inited) {

alert("not inited");

return;

}

var oldPageAnchor = document.getElementById('pg'+this.currentPage);

oldPageAnchor.className = 'pg-normal';

this.currentPage = pageNumber;

var newPageAnchor = document.getElementById('pg'+this.currentPage);

newPageAnchor.className = 'pg-selected';

var from = (pageNumber - 1) * itemsPerPage + 1;

var to = from + itemsPerPage - 1;

this.showRecords(from, to);

}

this.prev = function() {

if (this.currentPage > 1)

this.showPage(this.currentPage - 1);

}

this.next = function() {

if (this.currentPage < this.pages) {

this.showPage(this.currentPage + 1);

}

}

this.init = function() {

var rows = document.getElementById(tableName).rows;

var records = (rows.length - 1);

this.pages = Math.ceil(records / itemsPerPage);

this.inited = true;

}

this.showPageNav = function(pagerName, positionId) {

if (! this.inited) {

alert("not inited");

return;

}

var element = document.getElementById(positionId);

var pagerHtml = '<span onclick="' + pagerName + '.prev();" class="pg-normal"> ?Prev </span> ';

for (var page = 1; page <= this.pages; page++)

pagerHtml += '<span id="pg' + page + '" class="pg-normal" onclick="' + pagerName + '.showPage(' + page + ');">' + 

page + '</span> ';

pagerHtml += '<span onclick="'+pagerName+'.next();" class="pg-normal"> Next ?/span>';

element.innerHTML = pagerHtml;

}

}

</script>
```

Comment: What doctype are you using?

Comment: What are the line numbers?  The errors contain line numbers, I suspect hat if you match them up to code, the problems will be easy to fix.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/66837/218196 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA.

Comment: Any reason you're writing xHTML instead of simply html? Html5 is so much easier to write and validate and at this moment has better support on browsers than xHTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I havent done this for a long time, but you can wrap you script like this:

```
<script type="javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    //Your JS Code

    //]]>
</script>
```

This will stop W3C validator from parsing your JS as markup.

Comment: @Rob I believe the comments work as well for the W3C validator, but recall for sure that this works.  But the `//<!--` way probably works as well.

Comment: The reason why this works is that in XML (and XHTML is an XML dialect), contents which contains characters such as `<`, must be enclosed in `<![CDATA[` directives.

Comment: Hi Martenljn,

Thanks for your answering. It is need to including // as well?

Comment: @Cally in front of `//<!CDATA` yes.  In front of `//Your JS Code` no.

Comment: @marteljn oh..great!! is working, thanks & appreciated your help =)

Comment: @Cally: Depends. It's safer to include it, but of it's really interpreted as XHTML (and not HTML), it is not necessary.