# What is the best way to declare script tag in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html

I have seen many different ways in declaring script tag. Some of them are:

Variation 1:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     //some javascript here
 </script>
```

Variation 2:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     //<![CDATA[
     // some javascript here
     //]]>
</script>
```

Variation 3:

```
 <script language="javascript">
     //some javascript here
 </script>
```

Variation 4:

```
       <script>
          //some javascript here
       </script>
```

There are also other variations as well. When we work in HTML5 + js then which way is more appropriate in declaring Script tag?

Comment: Aside from variation 3 (I'm not 100% sure so I'mma leave it out), they're all valid ways. It's basically personal preference at this point as far as I know

Comment: do checkout: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag

Answer (score 5):

In HTML5 you don't need an additional attribute like "type". Just declare JavaScript code with `<script></script>`.

Answer (score 3):

The default language for `script` tags is Javascript, so there is no need to declare it explicitly.

```
<script>
//some javascript here
</script>
```

Is the least verbose and most appropriate way to declare a Javascript block. The others are valid, but just redundant.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script):

> **type:** If this attribute is absent, the script is treated as JavaScript
>
> **language:** Like the type attribute, this attribute identifies the
>   scripting language in use. Unlike the type attribute, however, this
>   attribute’s possible values were never standardized. The type
>   attribute should be used instead.

Variation 3 should not be used as the `language` attribute was never standardized and is marked on MDN as deprecated.

As Jack points out, the use of `<![CDATA[]]>` is also redundant as it is only used to make sure a document can be parsed as XML.

Comment: The best answer of the lot so far. I'd personally add an explanation that adding CDATA is entirely obsolete as per here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag

Comment: @JackBracken - The top answer from the question you link to says that there are situations where CDATA is useful and not obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

```
Version 2 : format
```

> It skip looking into javascript implementation for W3C validator.
>
> Also it allow to identified by the browser that the JavaScript or text written inside the  tag

See this link for More detail:

[**Javascript and XHTML**](http://javascript.about.com/library/blxhtml.htm)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is the default scripting language for HTML5, so you can just use script tag without any type attribute.
However, with HTML5, you get some additional features like, async.