# document type does not allow element "h4" here

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't find out what the problem is with this line of code:

`…sc', '<h4 class="vtem_news_show_title">Nesmet El Bouhaira</h4>');$('#vtem1 img…`

This is the error message I receive:

```
**document type does not allow element "h4" here**
```

What do I need to change?

---

This is the whole `<script>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var vtemnewsshow = jQuery.noConflict();
    (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#vtem0 img').data('ad-desc', '<h4>Nesmet El Bouhaira</h4>');
            $('#vtem1 img').data('ad-desc', '<h4>Tunis Mall 1</h4>');
            $('#vtemnewsshowid89-newsshow').adGallery({
                loader_image: 'http://laselection-immobiliere.com/modules/mod_vtem_news_show/images/loading.gif',
                update_window_hash: false,
                start_at_index: 0,
                bottompos: 20,
                thumb_opacity: 0.8,
                animation_speed: 400,
                width: '970',
                height: '340',
                display_next_and_prev: 1,
                display_back_and_forward: 0,
                slideshow: {
                    autostart: 1,
                    speed: 5000
                },
                effect: 'slide-hori', // or 'slide-vert', 'fade', or 'resize', 'none'
                enable_keyboard_move: 1,
                link_target: '_self'
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: The whole `<script>` block would be helpful, but I bet, it doesn't start with `//<![CDATA[` and doesn't end in `//]]>` which makes the validator interpret the tag's contents as actual markup.

Comment: What tags are around the *<h4>* element?

Comment: You should post all the script here, not just part of a sentence

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If your Javascript contains HTML tags, a validator considers these part of the document, *unless* you prefix your code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
jQuery.data(element, '<h1>Hello, world.</h1>');
//]]>
</script>
```

You might have come across another way to resolve this issue:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.data(element, '<' + 'h1>Hello, world.<' + '/h1>');
</script>
```

This basically chops the string to "hide" the tags from a validator. It makes code harder to read and I'd never prefer this "hack" to the `CDATA` solution.

Please have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag), which is rather old but has a lot of answers.

Comment: There's so much wrong with this answer. First of all: `document.write`. Secondly: `document.write`. Did I mention `document.write`?

Comment: @Cerbrus - What's wrong with this answer isn't `document.write`, even before the edit.

Comment: `console.log()` some `<html>` makes no sense while [`document.write()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/802943/731947)

Comment: @Cerbrus This is an *example* to make a point about escaping the output not a best-use case example of how to get content into the document. Your downvote and the edit in particular are invalid. The latter I've rolled back.

Comment: @LinusKleen so by your logic, it's fine to introduce SQL/XSS/Shell injections into my examples, because they're just examples and there's **no way** that ***anyone*** would ***ever*** copy and paste it into his code, right? Even though there's no actual security vulnerability in your specific example, you're promoting `document.write` whether you want to or not.

Comment: @Cerbrus et.al. Are you even aware of the OP's *question*? In case you're not, it's not "how do I append content to my DOM". The fact aside that your personal distaste of a function leads you to conclude the answer were "wrong", you give no basis for this. And since this question isn't about `document.write` and the OP uses jQuery, I changed it to jQuery.