# JavaScript document.location.href seems to expect HTML

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

If I execute this in the IE 11 console:

```
document.location.href="a&amp;b";
```

I get an error saying:

```
Not found - The requested URL /a&b was not found on this server.
```

But should it not rather complain about `a&amp;b` not being found? The URL which happens to contain a HTML entity seems to be interpreted as HTML, despite nothing here actually being connected to HTML.

I came across this while having a GET parameter named `copy_from` in an onclick attribute, and despite escaping the ampersand correctly (`&amp;copy_from=`), the final URL showed up with a copyright character in it. (It works in IE by escaping the ampersand twice, but then it fails in other browsers.)

Am I missing something or is this an IE bug?

Comment: Isn't `&` a invalid char for the none query part of the url? So the behavior how a browser would handle `/a&amp;b`  is somehow undefined?

Comment: Running that in the *chrome* console doesn't give that result, so it looks like an IE bug.

Comment: I understood the href property to contain a fully fledged URI, including GET parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do think this is a bug. If, in javascript you have specified '/a&b', then the URL requested should have nothing to do with HTML entities. This is supported by the fact that most browsers try to redirect you to '/a&b', as expected.

I've seen lots of inconsistencies between browsers like this before.

It's probably the kind of thing someone (with lots more time than I) could find a way to exploit.

If the document is XHTML - and interpreted as XML - however, you are required to use a CDATA section around the inline javascript which includes the ampersands. e.g. [When is a CDATA section necessary within a script tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag).

In practice, this is rarely done, which is why this is probably a bug.