# "Error parsing XML: not well-formed" for javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing

I am getting an "Error parsing XML: not well-formed" message with the following line in javascript:

```
for (var i=1; i<=totalImgs; i++)
```

Removing  the `<` character from this line clears up the parsing error, but then the javascript doesn't work.  Are there any solutions to this?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.8

Answer (score 1):

Here are three possible solutions:

- Move the script into a separate `.js` file so that the XML parser won't see it.
- Surround the script contents with `<![CDATA[ ]]>` (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag) for further details).
- Use an [XML character entity reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) (i.e. `&lt;`) instead of a literal `<`