# Unfamiliar Javascript syntax/hack

Tags: html, formatting, script-tag

I'm perusing some source, and I see this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery/jquery.1.7.1.js">//]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/swfobject_modified.js">//]]>
</script>
```

There's a dozen or so dependencies in the head listed in such a fashion, what is the purpose of the `//]]>` after each script tag?

The code looks a bit old school, and is set to emulate IE7 in compat:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

Just curious really, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My best guess is that the script code was originally put in a CDATA section like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
//<![CDATA[
//]]>
</script>
```

When deleting `//<![CDATA[` ([which wasn't needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66865/3903374) since it's referring to an external source file), they simply neglected to remove the final `//]]`.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, just messy cleanup, but it's after every single JS dependency, 3rd party or proprietary. Let's see if we guessed right or otherwise...

Comment: Alright, I'm calling it, its some poor cleanup - I couldn't find anything pertinent. I had hoped there was some cool trick I never knew about to make files instantly download using magic. Nevermind.

Comment: "make files instantly download using magic" - that'd be Pied Piper from Silicon Valley, I guess.