# How to pass multiple argument in a hyperlink in java scriipt?

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I am trying to create a dynamic hyperlink using JavaScript. I am using "&" to pass multiple arguments, but ii am getting a parsing error.

JavaScript:

```
<script>
    function visitPage() {
        var phn = document.getElementById("bid").value;
        var totalprice = spans[3].innerHTML;
        window.location.href = 'https://www.instamojo.com/stayuncle/payments-for-stayuncle?data_amount='
            + totalprice + '&' + 'data_Field_68092=' + phn;
    }
</script>
```

Error:

> The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.

I tried to fix it by passing `'&AMP'`, which resulted in the link looking like this: 
`https://www.instamojo.com/stayuncle/payments-for-stayuncle/?data_amount=1374.75&AMPdata_Field_68092=Hotel%20Delhi%20Airport%20Link`

'**&AMP**' is still in link, instead of getting converted to an ampersand itself.

I have also removed the semicolon (`;`) after every `&AMP`, because it didn't let me post actual problem.

Comment: What is in `phn` and `totalprice`?

Comment: @Jens I was using &amp;  only . I was not able to type and to make it distinguish so I make it capital in my question

Comment: @jfriend00 totalprice containing  double like 112.00 and phn is integer in nature

Comment: @vinayakj  I tried with encodeURIComponent() .its not changing domain .Its mixing two domain .. one is local host and another is on which I am directing it .

Comment: Please do not tag a Javascript question with [tag:java]. They are totally different languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var a = 1374.75;
var b = 'Hotel Delhi Airport Link';
var url = 'https://www.instamojo.com/stayuncle/payments-for-stayuncle'
var link = decodeURIComponent(url+'?data_amount='+a+'&data_Field_68092='+b)

alert("Redirecting to"+ link)
location.href = link
```

Alsso need to wrap the code in `<![CDATA[ code //]]>` as using the Thymeleaf.

Comment: I have used same code that you have written but getting this error  **The reference to entity "data_Field_68092" must end with the ';' delimiter.** . I am using thymeleaf at UI front. Please let me know how can I resolve this

Comment: you need to create small fiddle, as above code runs correctly

Comment: you need to provide exact code snippet that is causing problem, as above code in javascript works correctly

Comment: after adding // <![CDATA[   your code //]]>  .YOur code was working for me . As am using  thymeleaf  and it based on XML that's why I was getting parsing error and it resolved after addition of  // <![CDATA[. I also added code snap below

Answer (score 1):

As I am using Thymeleaf as a front end and Thymeleaf using XML underlying.so in such scenario CDATA section is required. Here is code snap that work for me. for more detail refer this section 
[When is a CDATA section necessary within a script tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag)

```js
 // <![CDATA[

    var a = 1374.75;
var b = 'Hotel Delhi Airport Link';

var link = decodeURIComponent('https://www.instamojo.com/stayuncle/payments-for-stayuncle?data_amount='+a+'&data_Field_68092='+b)

alert("Redirecting to"+ link)
location.href = link

 //]]>
```

After adding //  work for me as Thymeleaf under lying using XML so To implement & and other special symbol need to add "

Comment: ohk.. didnt know about the Thymeleaf way.. was considering as just the code snippet from javascript file..

Answer (score 0):

```js
var totalprice = 1374.75;
var name = 'Hotel Delhi Airport Link';
var email='n@gmail.com';
var phn='1111111111'

var link = decodeURIComponent('http://www.example.com?data_amount='+totalprice+'&amp;'+'data_name='+name+'&amp;'+'data_email='+email+'&amp;'+'data_phn='+phn)

alert("Redirecting to"+ link)
location.href = link
```

Comment: @vinayakj I have posted code snap by some addition into your code . here I have used '&amp;' instead of & because Thymeleaf show this parsing error  on use of  (&)   **HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Exception parsing document:The reference to entity "data_Field_68092" must end with the ';' delimiter.** but '&amp;' is not converting to &

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x = 1374.75;
var y = 'Tesxt Data';

var link = decodeURIComponent('URL='+x+'With Field='+y)

alert("Redirecting to"+ link)
location.href = link
```

Comment: How can I pass two more arguments? let say y & z ?

Comment: I tried but there is no separation between elements that we are passing .(+) treated everything as one .Look at the out come of our code snippet .It doesn't differentiating value of x from field "With Filed" .all treated as one parameter