# Magento Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I am just adding a ticker in my website and using A script in js file . but facing
error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

```
<![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('.simple-marquee-container').SimpleMarquee();

});
</script>]]>
```

Please help me

Comment: `<![CDATA[`…`]]>` belongs _inside_ the `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the `<![CDATA[` and `]]>`. Or put it on the inside of `script`, with `//` in front, as a comment.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.simple-marquee-container').SimpleMarquee();
});
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(function() {
    $('.simple-marquee-container').SimpleMarquee();
});
//]]>
</script>
```

See also, [when and why `CDATA` is needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag).

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('.simple-marquee-container').SimpleMarquee();
});
</script> this code also showing same error

Comment: We would need more info then. Where have you included the code? Is the snippet really the problem? Are there more error details? Please edit your question with more information. @SanjayYadav

Comment: I have no more error I am including page link please  view this and if need more any thing from my side then let me know please.(http://dev.factorydirectmedical.com/?)

Comment: Took a short look. Your HTML is full of bugs, like unclosed tags. So clean up the HTML first, that may solve the problem or you will better see whats wrong. Actually your page is a mess. @SanjayYadav

Answer (score 0):

if this code is in js file then just put this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.simple-marquee-container').SimpleMarquee();
});
</script>
```

we use CDATA when we add js in xml file directly as per I know May be I was wrong this is the concept