# Adding a class attribute in a condition with javascript

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I'm trying to write a script to add a class attribute to an element only if another element contains a certain attribute. This is the HTML source code:

```
      <fieldset class="step1 option0">
                <legend><b>Options</b></legend>
                <p>
                    <input id="question_1" name="group_1" type="radio" MadCap:conditions="guideConditions.ProductA" />
                    <label for="question_1" MadCap:conditions="guideConditions.ProductA">Option 1</label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input id="question_2" name="group_1" type="radio" />
                    <label for="question_2">Option 2</label>
                </p>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset id="question_1_1" class="hide step2 option1" MadCap:conditions="guideConditions.ProductA">
                <legend><b>Outcome:</b>
                </legend>
                <p>This should be only displayed for product A</p>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="question_1_2" class="hide step2">
                <legend><b>Outcome:</b>
                </legend>
                <p>I want to add an "option1" class if the element with id="question_1" contains the property "MadCap:conditions". If the property is not present, "option2" should be added</p>
            </fieldset>
```

I want the script to add an "option1" class to the fieldset with id "question_1_2" if the input element with id "question_1" contains the attribute "MadCap:conditions". Otherwise, the script should add an "option2" class (fieldset class="hide step2 **option1**" id="question_1_2" versus fieldset class="hide step2 **option2**" id="question_1_2")

This is what I've tried, but it does not seem to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[/>
    var element =  document.getElementById("question_1"), 
    var element2 = document.getElementById("question_1_2"), 
    if (element.hasAttribute('MadCap:conditions')) { // "generate the class dynamically" 
        element2.classList.add("option1")
    } else { // "increment it by one" 
        element2.classList.add("option2")
    } 
/]]>*/
</script>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure your `script` is place *below* the content it is referring to? If not, those elements are not yet in the DOM and the script will not find them.

Comment: Thank you @trincot. I've placed the script right after the form containing the fielsets in the body element of my html...Is the script I wrote correctly formatted? I've added it like this:  <script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/>
  var element = document.getElementById("question_1"),
  var element2 = document.getElementById("question_1_2"),
  if (element.hasAttribute('MadCap:conditions')) {
  // "generate the class dynamically"
  element2.classList.add("option1")}  
  else {
  // "increment it by one"
  element2.classList.add("option2")}
  /*]]>*/</script>

Comment: You should include it in your question, exactly like you have it. But it looks like you put all the code in a big comment block... NB: a comma is not a statement separator.

Comment: I updated your question with that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script element uses `CDATA` in a wrong way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[/>
    var element =  document.getElementById("question_1"), 
    var element2 = document.getElementById("question_1_2"), 
    if (element.hasAttribute('MadCap:conditions')) { // "generate the class dynamically" 
        element2.classList.add("option1")
    } else { // "increment it by one" 
        element2.classList.add("option2")
    } 
/]]>*/
</script>
```

Even the syntax highlighting on this site already hints that something is wrong. The `/* */` wraps around all of your code, so it is not parsed as code.

Nowadays there is seldom a reason to apply this CDATA pattern. See [When is a CDATA section necessary within a script tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag).

Also, you should use semicolons to separate statements, not commas.

If you really need the `CDATA` to be there, then only put the `CDATA` parts inside JavaScript comments. For instance like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[/>
    var element =  document.getElementById("question_1");
    var element2 = document.getElementById("question_1_2"); 
    if (element.hasAttribute('MadCap:conditions')) { // "generate the class dynamically" 
        element2.classList.add("option1");
    } else { // "increment it by one" 
        element2.classList.add("option2");
    } 
// ]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With comma you got `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'var'` so if you put semicolon it seems to work:

```
  var element = document.getElementById("question_1");
  var element2 = document.getElementById("question_1_2");
  if (element.hasAttribute('MadCap:conditions')) {
    element2.classList.add("option1")}
  else {
    element2.classList.add("option2")}
```